# Is it possible to use a UUID in an NSSortDescriptor for NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

When using a `UUID` property of `NSManagedObject` in an `NSFetchedResultsController`, the application crashes with:

> -[__NSConcreteUUID compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

when the contents of `NSFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` change, but not when it is first loaded. When first loaded, the objects are sorted correctly by UUID.

This is how I create the `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```swift
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyObject> = MyObject.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(MyObject.uuid), ascending: true),
]

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(MyObject.tag), tag)

let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                            managedObjectContext: context,
                                            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                            cacheName: nil)
controller.delegate = self
    
do {
    try controller.performFetch()
} catch {
    fatalError("###\(#function): Failed to performFetch: \(error)")
}
```

To create the `NSManagedObject` (`MyObject` in the code above), I used the model editor to add a field "uuid" with the `UUID` type.

It seems that Core Data has no problem sorting by UUID at the SQL level, but after it loads the data and tries to maintain the sorting in memory, it tries to call `compare` on `_NSConcreteUUID` in some way, which doesn't exist as a method. This method could be implemented with byte or string comparison of the UUID.

Failed attempts:

- Adding `compare` as an extension to `UUID` or `NSUUID`
- Passing the `comparator` argument to `NSSortDescriptor` is not allowed by Core Data and will terminate the application

Maybe there is a workaround by using `Transformable` that will let it benefit from the native UUID type on the SQL side, but still be usable inside `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: Maybe you cans use `uuidString` and then compare on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to sort Core Data results using a `UUID` property. You would need to convert the UUID to a string if you want to use it for sorting.

Core Data doesn't actually sort on UUIDs when fetching. You can see this if you turn on Core Data SQLite debugging by adding `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 4` to the arguments in the build scheme in Xcode. When you sort on a numerical property like a time stamp, the debug output includes a SQL `ORDER BY` clause

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZEVENT t0 ORDER BY t0.ZTIMESTAMP DESC
```

If you try it with a `UUID` property, there's no `ORDER BY` clause. Core Data just ignores the sort descriptor. It won't crash but it's not sorting the results either.

I'm not sure why this is, because using the `sqlite3` command line tool to open up the SQLite file Core Data creates shows that a UUID property is represented as a SQLite `BLOB` field. SQLite can sort on `BLOB`, even though it doesn't usually make sense to do so.

I suggest filing a bug with Apple. I don't know what they'll think about how this should work, but it should definitely not ignore the sort descriptor and not print a console message of some kind.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, though what would be your preference when choosing between String(either 36/24bits) and Binary, saying space is a rather negligible factor?

Comment: I’d go with whatever format the data is already in, unless there’s some compelling reason to convert. If that’s not what you mean, ask a new question and explain things in more detail.